# Перевести таблицу Excel в двумерный массив PHP

Tags: массивы, php, excel

Здравствуйте,
Как можно перевести таблицу Excel в двумерный массив PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл типа xls, лучше конвертнуть в xlsx. Распаковать файл как обычный zip-архив. Находим необходимый лист по адресу xl/worksheets/sheetXX.xml, где "XX" - это номер листа. Также может понадобиться лист xl/sharedStrings.xml, если он есть, и xl/styles.xml. А дальше SimpleXML в помощь. И, скорее всего, придется хорошо повозиться с представлением данных.

Если необходимо данный процесс полностью автоматизировать, посмотреть в сторону готовых решений типа PHPExcel...

Если есть желание написать свой велосипед или более подробно узнать о структуре xml-файлов, используемых в xlsx, сообщить.

Если необходимо получить полностью готовое решение, не ко мне.

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel делает все...

Answer (score 0):

Пакет [fast-excel-reader](https://packagist.org/packages/avadim/fast-excel-reader):

```
use \avadim\FastExcelReader\Excel;

$file = __DIR__ . '/files/demo-01-base.xlsx';

// Open XLSX-file
$excel = Excel::open($file);

// Read all rows
$result = $excel->readRows();
```

И получаете в `$result` двумерный массив.